# How to reduce resistor heat?

Tags: resistors, resistance, heat

I have 240VAC main and from 2 sides of wire 2 resistors 1W 33k... After some time resistors heat up.

I don't know why is that?

By my calculation, when I have 1 resistor on 120VAC, then power of 33K resistor should be more then: 0.43636W, but I have 1W...

Anyone know what is problem, and why it heat?

Comment: Your resistor is dissipating .436363 Watts (as heat). Thereby raising it temperature. Hopefully to a equilibrium point.

Comment: Power into a resistor = heat.

Comment: How to reduce heat?

Comment: A resistor isn't magical, it doesn't just contain a 1W vacuum that'll make power go away. Elemental law of nature, you know, the conservation of power.

Comment: To reduce heat, reduce the current through the resistor. To reduce its temperature (for the same heat), improve its cooling.

Comment: How to reduce current? Also I think it's too much heat for 0.43636W....

Comment: *"from 2 sides of wire 2 resistors 1W 33k"* is gibberish.

Comment: Please stop quoting the power to 6 digits. '0.44W' is more than sufficient, given the tolerance of the mains and the resistor.

Comment: How to reduce the current? Reduce the voltage, increase the resistance, remove the resistors altogether... We don't know what your circuit is trying to achive, so we can only speculate how it could be done with less heat.

Comment: A resistor changes electrical energy to heat. 1W is the maximum power that your resistor is allowed to dissipate safely, it doesn't mean that it will always produce 1W - the actual power depends on the voltage across it and subsequent current though it. Also, heat is not necessarily a 'problem'; e.g. cooker, electric fire !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"After some time resistors heat up. I don't know why is that?"

It's because each resistor is dissipating about 1/2 watt.

A 1 watt resistor can safely dissipate 1 watt, and will not catch fire or do other nasty things. However, this does not mean that at 1/2 watt it will not get hot. The general rule is that, the more the power the higher the temperature. Due to various effects, running at half power will produce a temperature rise less than 1/2 the allowable maximum - but that does not mean it won't be hot.

Different resistor materials have different maximum temperatures. Resistors designed for high power are made to withstand quite high temperatures, and for [this manufacturer](http://www.ohmite.com/techdata/res_select.pdf) the upper limit to their resistors is more than 300 C above ambient. I've personally used power resistors that survived getting so hot that the solder connections melted (wirewound with vitreous body). So your version of "hot" may not be as much a problem as you think. YMMV, of course, so find the data sheet for your resistor to see what temperature is acceptable.